# How to in-app mail more then one textfields in ios Xcode?

Tags: ios, forms, uitextfield, email

I like to make a form for my app where the user can report me errors via mail. The form is ready but I can't set multiple `UITextfields` as Message Body.

Here is my code:

.h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *ios;

IBOutlet UITextField *iDevice;

IBOutlet UITextField *jailbreakstatus;

IBOutlet UITextField *otherstuff;
```

.m

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"david.goelzhaeuser@me.com", nil]];

    [composer setSubject:@"Feedback"];

    [composer setMessageBody: ios.text,iDevice.text, jailbreakstatus.text, otherstuff.text isHTML:NO];

    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    [composer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
}
```

I allready searched the web for solutions but I found nothing that helped me. Now you are my only hope:)

PS: Is it possible to make it like so:

UILable: UITextfield
UILable: UITextfield
UILable: UITextfield
UILable: UITextfield

Basicly this way:

iOS: 6.0
iDevice: iPhone 4
Jailbroken: No
Other stuff: Random

Do you understand it?

Comment: try this one `[composer setMessageBody: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",ios.text,iDevice.text, jailbreakstatus.text, otherstuff.text]isHTML:NO];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also can do like this

```
[composer setMessageBody: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@ \n%@ \n%@",ios.text,iDevice.text, jailbreakstatus.text, otherstuff.text]isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mBodyString = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"iOS:%@\n Device:%@\n Jailbreak:%@\n Other:%@",ios.text,iDevice.text,jailbreakstatus.text,otherstuff.text];

[composer setMessageBody:mBodyString isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: Is it possible to make UILable:UITextField [return] UILable:UITextField [return] UILable:UITextField [return] UILable:UITextField [return]